# How to redirect dynamic subdomains with multiple query parameters

Tags: .htaccess

I would like to redirect

```
domain.com/test.php?username=username&code1=849&code2=4d1
```

to

```
username.domain.com/849/4d1
```

with .htaccess

At the moment I have

```
RewriteRule ^test/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+) test.php?username=$1&code1=$2&code2=$3 [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(^.*)\.domain.com
RewriteRule ^(.*) test.php?username=%1&code1=%2&code2=%3 [NC]
```

The redirect works but the code (php)

```
$code1 = $_GET['code1'];
echo $code1;
```

is empty. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it!

So if you want to redirect

```
username.domain.com/849/4d1
```

to

```
domain.com/test.php?username=username&code1=849&code2=4d1
```

You need to add below code to your .htaccess file:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(^.*)\.domain.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)/([^/]+) test.php?username=%1&code1=$1&code2=$2 [NC]
```